# How to sort all the papers referenced by a given paper by citation count?

Tags: citations, cross-referencing

Here is what I want to do:

1. Given a paper, find the set of all papers referenced by it
2. Sort this set of papers by some "importance metric,"  for example, the citation count.

I find some ad-hoc tools (for example, research gate) to do #1 and there are a few databases (Web of Science, Scopus) to do #2, but the two steps are disconnected and there seems no easy way to bridge them automatically. I have been doing this manually, but it is very tedious.

Are there any efficient ways to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft Academic](https://academic.microsoft.com) provides an option to sort references of a paper by citation count. I am not aware how complete or accurate it is, but you could try it out. They also seem to provide an API for automated access.

Screenshot of an [example](https://academic.microsoft.com/paper/2618530766/reference/search?q=ImageNet%20classification%20with%20deep%20convolutional%20neural%20networks&qe=Or(Id%253D2194775991%252CId%253D2097117768%252CId%253D2108598243%252CId%253D2911964244%252CId%253D1904365287%252CId%253D1665214252%252CId%253D2546302380%252CId%253D2110764733%252CId%253D2130325614%252CId%253D1576445103%252CId%253D2141125852%252CId%253D2766736793%252CId%253D2108069432%252CId%253D2053229256%252CId%253D2134557905%252CId%253D2156163116%252CId%253D2015861736%252CId%253D2026942141%252CId%253D1499991161%252CId%253D2166049352%252CId%253D2169805405%252CId%253D2396976214%252CId%253D2097356275%252CId%253D2144161366%252CId%253D2061212083%252CId%253D2154579312%252CId%253D2101926813%252CId%253D1573503290%252CId%253D2565808444%252CId%253D2018435387)&f=&orderBy=0) for reference:
[image]

<sub>Note: I am not affiliated with this service.</sub>

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. It is saving me so much time. Thanks so much.

Comment: I tested it on a few papers and it works really well.